# using grpc get import error, undefined symbol: grpc_google_iam_credentials_create

Tags: python, grpc

I use grpc in ubuntu, when import the *_pb2.py which generated by run_codegen.sh, I got following ImportError:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
File "q_db_op.py", line 2, in <module>
import db_op_pb2
  File "/data/server/grpc/db_op_pb2.py", line 331, in <module>
from grpc.early_adopter import implementations
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/early_adopter/implementations.py", line 34, in <module>
from grpc._adapter import fore as _fore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/_adapter/fore.py", line 38, in <module>
from grpc._adapter import _intermediary_low as _low
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/_adapter/_intermediary_low.py", line 57, in <module>
from grpc._adapter import _low
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/_adapter/_low.py", line 31, in <module>
from grpc._adapter import _c
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/_adapter/_c.so: undefined symbol: grpc_google_iam_credentials_create
```

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This smells a bit like you've only installed gRPC Python and haven't yet installed the gRPC Core on your system. If that's the case the solution to your problem is to install the gRPC Core ("sudo apt-get install libgrpc-dev", see the [installation instructions](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/python#installation)).

Also take care that the version of the gRPC Core that you apt-get install (0.11, 0.12, or something later) is the same as the version of the grpcio PyPI package that you pip install (0.11, 0.12, or something later).

Comment: That's great, but it misses the fact that Nathaniel, who is quite possibly the best person in the world to answer this particular question, doesn't have enough reputation at this point to actually comment.

Comment: (I have edited my answer under the direction of an experienced Stack Overflow user to be more answery; I hope it's now what it needs to be?)